# WYSIWYG editing of HTML documents exported from Microsoft Excel

Tags: wysiwyg

Do WYSIWYG editors generally have problems editing HTML documents that has been exported by Microsoft programs like Excel?

I'm currently using TinyMCE, and I'm having trouble editing an html document that was saved by Excel.  The html file has a lot of inline "mso" css styles, which I'm guessing are microsoft specific.  TinyMCE can't render the html doc properly in the editor. Do these things generally break WYSIWYG editors like TinyMCE?

Are there WYSIWYG editors that circumvent these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the MS-specific styles are probably the issue.

The WYSIWYG editor for HTML produced by Excel is Excel. It understands all of the styles and so forth. If you don't want to use Excel as your editor, don't use Excel to produce the HTML in the first place; use something else instead.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Frontpage might fare better. I don't have it installed so I can't test that theory.

From a code cleanliness standpoint, it's not a good idea to be exporting from Excel or Word in the first place. I have a hunch that you're receiving the exported file from someone else.